# Perl print more lines

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I am new in `Perl` and i want to print more than just the first regex match.
The txt file contains 57 times `shutdown`, with the following code i just get back the first match, than it stops.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;
use autodie;

my $dir = path("H:/Perl");

my $file = $dir->child("test.txt");

my $content = $file->slurp_utf8();

my $file_handle = $file->openr_utf8();

(my $test) = $content =~ m/^.+$(?=\s+shutdown)/mg;{
print "$test\n"; 
}
```

I tried an `while loop` but i didn't worked. Thanks for help.

Edit:
Here is some example data:

```
interface port-channelxyc
description provdb002
shutdown
switchport access vlan 123
spanning-tree port type edge

interface port-channel456
description provdb002
switchport access vlan 32
spanning-tree port type edge

interface port-channel200
shutdown
```

i got back only:
'description provdb002'
then it stops, but i want get also the next one: 'interface port-channel200' and so on ... hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Your regex _does_ return a list with `/g`; so assign it to an array: `my @ary = $content =~ ...`

Comment: Can you give some example data please, and desired output? At risk of sounding daft, is the file definitely `utf8` because that's not all that common? The problem with that pattern is that it'll return a list, but I'm not sure it'll be capturing the right thing.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the data there. It's impossible to tell where the line breaks are if you put it in a comment.

Comment: If all your files are indeed like this you don't need `slurp_utf8`, just as @Sobrique suspected, but rather `slurp` (and then assign your matches to an array). The regex does require some discussion though

Comment: OK, with your sample input - what's your desired output?

Answer (score 3):

OK, your data looks like it's blank-line delimited.

Handily, perl supports that really easily, using `$/` and setting it to `''`.

And so you can iterate your file like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '';
while ( <> ) {
   my %this_int = m/([\w\-]+) ?(.*)/g; 

   if ( exists $this_int{'shutdown'} ) { 
       print  $this_int{'interface'}, " ", $this_int{'description'} // ''," is shut down\n";
   }
}
```

Which for your sample data will print:

```
port-channelxyc provdb002 is shut down
port-channel200  is shut down
```

Comment: That's a pretty nice idea to assign the results of `m/…()…()…/g` directly to a `%hash`. I will remember that.